# Erro :non-static method set(int,int) na MainActivity

Tags: java, android

Estava copilando os códigos quando cheguei no final e deparei com erros na  `MainActivity`, estou usando API 16,alguém me ajuda ?

[image: erro na Main Activity]

**código **

```
 import android.app.AlarmManager;
 import android.app.NotificationManager;
 import android.app.PendingIntent;
 import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.icu.util.Calendar;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
 import android.view.View;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void  onClick(View view){

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            Calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,18);
            Calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,45);
            Calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Notification_reciever.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
        }
    });
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema começa no `import` que não está correto. No topo o `Calendar` está a ser importado com :

```
import android.icu.util.Calendar;
```

Quando o código que está a ser utilizado do `Calendar` refere-re a biblioteca *standard* do java em `java.util`. Logo o `import` citado acima devia ser trocado por:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
```

Para além disso a inicialização/utilização do `Calendar`:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

Calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,18);
Calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,45);
Calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);
```

Não está correta também. Repare que o `Calendar.set` está a ser feito com inicial maiúscula, logo refere a classe `Calendar` e não o objeto `calendar` criado acima que era o que se pretendia.

Troque este bloco de código por:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,18);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,45);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);
```